# Connecting cable box to laptop to view TV in real time

Tags: hdmi, video, television

I have a cable box in my room and wish to connect it to my laptop, Asus N56VB. The cable box has a HDMI output, and the laptop itself has a HDMI port as well, which I know is an output only.

My question is, can I use some device, like a HDMI capture box, to watch TV in real time?

The cable box has the following connectors:

- [Picture number 1](http://s23.postimg.org/4z49e95uz/IMG_20150924_190746.jpg)
- [Picture number 2](http://s2.postimg.org/ujb5yfjex/IMG_20150924_192021.jpg)

Possible devices:

- [AVerMedia AVerCapture HD](http://amzn.com/B00I0QZMPE)
- [HDMI-Cloner Box](http://amzn.com/B00TF9MCXU)

I have been told that I can use them, but it seems strange because they pass the video/audio using a HDMI cable, but as far as I know, the HDMI port on my laptop is output only.

Or maybe I need the [Magewell HDMI to USB 3.0 Video Capture Dongle](http://amzn.com/B00I16VQOY).

Thank you.

Comment: The HDMI port on a laptop is almost always a output only connector unless explicitly specified its a input connector. The AVerMedia capture card is a great device to capture video in real time. It is easy to use and have a lot of features.

Comment: So you want to watch tv on your pc through the cablebox?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1Z9Ax61qWw
here's how you can use your laptop as a secondary screen with another PC. I'm pretty sure your cable box won't manage to send a video signal to the network.
In either case, the HDMI is not the solution

Comment: @RudraMatroja thank you, but the video is a for a completely different purpose, it doesn't help. And yes, I want to watch TV on my laptop screen by using the cablebox in my room. By the way, I updated to post.

Comment: You also should note that the cable box probably uses DRM (HDCP) on the output, so your capture card needs to be HDCP compatible, or you need to install a HDCP stripping device of some sort between cable box and capture card.

Answer (score 1):

**Get a capture card!** The AVerMedia AVerCapture HD that you linked is along the lines of what you want, but it's not my top recommendation.

Take a look at the [Elgato HD60 S](https://www.elgato.com/en/gaming/game-capture-hd60-s), a low latency USB 3.0 HDMI capture card (should work just fine with your laptop's USB 3.0 ports.) It's not exactly cheap by any means at $180, but it's the best I know of.

You should then be able to monitor the capture card's video using either Elgato's provided software or something like [VLC](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Use_a_capture_card/) or [OBS](https://obsproject.com).